# A delicate trigonometric inequality

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I would like to show that for $u\in[0,\pi/2]$ we have
$$\frac{u}{\sin(u)}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{u-\sin(u)\cos(u)}{u-\sin(u)} \geq 2 $$
Any idea?

Comment: for $u=0$ we have a problem in the inequality

Comment: No near zero if you use power series you have the inequality.
But I did not find how to prove it on the interval $[0,\pi/2]$.

Comment: You can try taking the derivative and showing that it's strictly increasing on the open interval.  However that will be quite messy.

Comment: @Babyblog it's defined everywhere on the interval except 0.  That is a removable discontinuity though.  It also doesn't really matter though because the limit is $2$ there if I did my math correctly.

Comment: I tried this but it is not easy to prove that the derivative is positive...
I was not able to prove it in fact.

Comment: A natural thing to try is to multiply with $(u - \sin (u))\cdot \sin (u)$ and see whether differentiating that leads to anything. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes I tried this, I think I tried every elementary ideas.
I tried a lot of things during hours, but it seems very hard to prove this.

Answer (score 1):

Two inequalities. The first one

$$\frac{u}{\sin  u}\geq  1+\frac{u^2}{6}$$

is easy to prove using power series. The second one

$$1-\cos  u\geq  \frac{u^2}{2}-\frac{u^4}{24}\geq  \frac{u-\sin  u}{\sin  u}\left(3-\frac{3u^2}{5}\right)$$

can also be derived using power series and can be rewritten as

$$\frac{\sin  u(1-\cos  u)}{u-\sin  u}\geq  3-\frac{3u^2}{5}$$
Multiply this last inequality by $1/4$ and add to the first inequality above to get

$$\frac{u}{\sin  u}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{\sin  u(1-\cos  u)}{u-\sin  u}\geq  \frac{7}{4}+\frac{u^2}{60}\geq \frac{7}{4}$$

Now add $\frac{1}{4}$ to both sides and simplify

$$\frac{u}{\sin  u}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{u-\sin  u \cos  u}{u-\sin  u}\geq  2$$

Comment: I am ok for $u$ near zero. I can check this on matlab, but I can't prove your inequalities with power series on all the interval $[0,\pi/2]$.

Comment: I don't understand why it's true on $[0,\pi/2]$.

Comment: @Babyblog I was referring to inequalities such as $\sin  u \leq  u$ and $\sin  u \leq  u-\frac{u^3}{6}+\frac{u^5}{120}$ which are valid in the interval $[0,\pi /2]$. If we multiply this second inequality by $1+\frac{u^2}{6}$ we can see that $\left(1+\frac{u^2}{6}\right)\sin  u \leq  u$